# C Sharp Generic Dapper Query Joining two tables

Tags: c#, generics, join, dapper, multiple-tables

I am a c# noobie, but here is the gist of what I am trying to do:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T, K>(string schemaName) where T : GenericModel
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT * from " +
            schemaName + "." + T.getTableName() + " primaryTable LEFT JOIN " +
            schemaName + "." + K.getTableName() +
            " ForeignTable on ForeignTable.id = primaryTable." + T.getForeignFieldName();

        return _connection.Query<T, K, T>(sql, (primary, foreign) =>
        { (primary = T.getForeignFieldName()) = foreign; return primary; });
    }
```

As an example T= Employee and K = Person

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll(string schemaName)
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT * from " + schemaName + 
            ".Employee primaryTable LEFT JOIN " + 
            schemaName + ".Person ForeignTable "+
            "on ForeignTable.id = primaryTable.person_id";
        return _connection.Query<EmployeeModel, PersonModel, EmployeeModel>
            (sql, (primary, foreign) => { primary.person = foreign; return primary; });
    }
```

`GenericModel` has the `getForeignFieldName()` and `getTableName()` which are shadowed by the derived classes (`Employee` and `Person`)

The example Models might look like:

```
Person {
  int id;
  string Name;
  string address;
  int age;
}

Employee {
  int id;
  int person_id;
  Person person;
  double salary;
```

}

Of course the generic solution doesn't work and I'm aware of sql injection. I just want to a generic method that I can use the way I have described with Dapper's Query() function.

In other words, how do you write a generic function that can do this: [Dapper's Multi Mapping](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multi-mapping)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Consider using a view / stored procedure instead...

Comment: @Milney Consider two overloads: one that returns just Employee data and a Null person, another that returns Person data when an Employee is queried. Now make it generic.... that's way too many views (many tables with similary structure). Whereas with a query, we can call the overload whenever we need the Person data as well

Answer (score 0):

Yup, sorry, but in the friendliest way - you've strayed off the reservation :-) The creation of a query is the moment where you *specify* what data you want, and what objects it gets returned to. People use dynamically constructed SQL to fiddle with the WHERE or ORDER BY clauses, but that's already a total anti-pattern in my view. By postponing the eventual decision about what tables, you've got a class that adds no value. Worse, you cut off vital possibilities, like a WHERE clause, or limiting the columns returned. In polite society, it's considered somewhat louche to ask for all columns in all rows from two joined tables!

Moral of the story, don't try and write 1 query that will do everything. Write more, smaller queries that bring back just what you need, just when you need it.

Comment: I see your point. I was helping out someone who wanted the generated  POCOS to contain a "GetAll()" method that returns all columns. Although that's an easy task, I think it's too repetitive, and hence the question.

Comment: No problem. I never understood anything about generating POCOs. Who or what is generating the POCOs? A GetAll() method, if you want one, would generally be on a repository, not on a POCO. The idea of a POCO is that it is ["Persistence Ignorant"](http://codeidol.com/community/dotnet/poco-as-a-lifestyle/9476/)

Comment: A helpful T4 script does the generation by reading the db information schema. It's just way easier to have each generated POCO contain a GetAll() on creation, rather than write them at later stage. I am strictly opposed to the POCO contain anything other than database columns, but hey! Life's rarely fair.

Comment: Yup, but the POCO will be based on your tables, not on a query. I wasn't going to mention it, but you will be happier and live longer if keep tables in your DB, objects in your app, and the delicate link between these two worlds are your queries, with POCOs generated by [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst), (disclaimer, which I wrote).

Comment: And as a happy side effect, QueryFirst will remove the temptation to dynamically build SQL with string methods :-)